# django loop inside loop is not working print on teamplates

Tags: django, django-templates

i am using django framework with python2.7 and in model i am receiving the following values as a query resultset 

`{
   "receivable": -90786.82,
   "payable": 8826.72,
   "receivable_aging":    {
      "age5": 235114.91999999998,
      "age4": 235114.91999999998,
      "age3": 0,
      "age2": 0,
      "age1": 0,
      "range":       [
         {"age5": "overdue in 10 days"},
         {"age1": "<30"},
         {"age2": "30-60"},
         {"age3": "60-90"},
         {"age4": ">90"}
      ],
      "overdue": 235114.91999999998
   }
}`

by the above result set i want to display in django template as below
**receivable_aging > range**

```
>90 is has 0    #0 is from receivable_aging.age1 & >90 is from 
                #receivable_aging.range.age1
30-60 is has 0  #0 is from receivable_aging.age2 & 30-60 is from
                #receivable_aging.range.age1
```

I new here , i tried lot of methods but not working pls help me on this

my tries are,

```
{% for key, value in response_bills.receivable_aging.items reversed %}
                                <div class="invoice-box-content">
                            <span class="invoice-box-text">

                                31 - 60 Days
                            </span>

                            {% if key not in "age5,range,overdue" %}

                                    <span class="invoice-box-value">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr fa-black fa-4" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ value }}
                            </span>

                            {% endif %}
                            </div>

                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you please more clear, what you want exact O/P. thanks

Comment: @AnkitK.Rathod  i want to print this -> `>90 is has 0    #0 is from receivable_aging.age1 & >90 is from 
                #receivable_aging.range.age1
30-60 is has 0  #0 is from receivable_aging.age2 & 30-60 is from
                #receivable_aging.range.age1`